# Magento home page loading without css

Tags: magento

http://skgowlar-001-site1.smarterasp.net/

Suddenly stopped working once installed new theme, just brings up page with no csss or formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the settings of your theme from admin? System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design

Also from what I see you have some misspelled links:

> h:\root\home\skgowlar-001\www\site1\skin\frontend\base\default\css/print.css

This is a local link, probably should look like

> http://skgowlar-001-site1.smarterasp.net/skin/frontend/base/default/css/print.css

and should point to your theme's folder, not base/default.
Try using Magento methods to get your URLs right: Mage::getUrl(), Mage::getBaseUrl() or look into Mage_Core_Helper_Url for more methods.